# Most efficient way to get XML data from a file in App_Data and cast it to IQueryable<MyModel>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am converting an existing WebForms application to MVC5.   There is data, stored in an XML file within the */App_Data* folder.  I have created a model that has all the matching items.   I need to fetch the data from this XML file and then return that as an *IQueryable*.

What is going to be the most efficient / best practice way of doing it?   Any simple examples would be great.

**CLARIFICATION**
I know of various ways to get data from XML.   The question revolves more about getting that data into the IQueryable.

**This is my model:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Framework.Models
{
    public class NewsModel
    {
        public NewsModel()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            Summary = string.Empty;
            Image = string.Empty;
            ImageWidth = 0;
            ImageHeight = 0;
            ImageSrcSet = string.Empty;
            ImageSizes = string.Empty;
            Url = new Uri("#");
            UrlText = string.Empty;
            UrlTarget = "_self";
            Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public String Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Summary")]
        public String Summary { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public String Image { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ImageWidth")]
        public int ImageWidth { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ImageHeight")]
        public int ImageHeight { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ImageSrcSet")]
        public String ImageSrcSet { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ImageSizes")]
        public String ImageSizes { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Url")]
        public Uri Url { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UrlText")]
        public String UrlText { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UrlTarget")]
        public String UrlTarget { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**This is my XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<News>
    <Item>
        <Title><![CDATA[Example Title 01]]></Title>
        <Summary>
            <![CDATA[
                Example Text 01
            ]]>
        </Summary>
        <Image><![CDATA[]]></Image>
        <ImageWidth>1420</ImageWidth>
        <ImageHeight>480</ImageHeight>
        <ImageAlignment>left</ImageAlignment>
        <ImageSrcSet><![CDATA[]]></ImageSrcSet>
        <ImageSizes><![CDATA[]]></ImageSizes>
        <Url><![CDATA[]]></Url>
        <UrlText><![CDATA[]]></UrlText>
        <UrlTarget>_blank</UrlTarget>
        <Date><![CDATA[05/01/2009]]></Date>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title><![CDATA[Example Title 02]]></Title>
        <Summary>
            <![CDATA[
                Example Text 02
            ]]>
        </Summary>
        <Image><![CDATA[]]></Image>
        <ImageWidth>920</ImageWidth>
        <ImageHeight>480</ImageHeight>
        <ImageAlignment>left</ImageAlignment>
        <ImageSrcSet><![CDATA[]]></ImageSrcSet>
        <ImageSizes><![CDATA[]]></ImageSizes>
        <Url><![CDATA[]]></Url>
        <UrlText><![CDATA[]]></UrlText>
        <UrlTarget>_self</UrlTarget>
        <Date><![CDATA[05/01/2009]]></Date>
    </Item>
</News>
```

Comment: linq to xml and then you select the result into your model.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the opposite of what I wanted to do ... I am trying to get data FROM an XML document, not create one.   Or is Linq to XML just poorly named?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Do you really need *Most efficient way*? or would a woking solution enough?

Comment: Linq to Xml lets you you read from Xml and create either new Xml or new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Framework.Models.News));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Framework.Models.News news = (Framework.Models.News)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }

}
namespace Framework.Models
{

    [XmlRoot("News")]
    public class News
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public List<NewsModel> newsModel { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot("Item")]
    public class NewsModel
    {
        public NewsModel()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            Summary = string.Empty;
            Image = string.Empty;
            ImageWidth = 0;
            ImageHeight = 0;
            ImageSrcSet = string.Empty;
            ImageSizes = string.Empty;
            Url = "#";
            UrlText = string.Empty;
            UrlTarget = "_self";
            //Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [XmlElement("Title")]
        public String Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Summary")]
        public String Summary { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Image")]
        public String Image { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ImageWidth")]
        public int ImageWidth { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ImageHeight")]
        public int ImageHeight { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ImageSrcSet")]
        public String ImageSrcSet { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ImageSizes")]
        public String ImageSizes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("UrlText")]
        public String UrlText { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("UrlTarget")]
        public String UrlTarget { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have you have code to create your object you can get it into an IQueryable like so:

```
NewsModel newsModel = CreateNewsModel();
var query = new [] { newsModel }.AsQueryable();
```